# JTable displays true/false instead of a CheckBox although "getColumnClass" is implemented

Tags: java

I have a JTable in which I want to display Boolean-values in form of CheckBoxes, which should be able to be edited (get checked/unchecked).

In order to accomplish that, I have implemented a subclass of AbstractTableModel with all needed methods, getColumnClass and isCellEditable implemented.

The problem is, that instead of a CheckBox, true/false is displayed. Only when I click on the cell, the getColumnClass-Method is called and the CheckBox appears for a short period of time.

I have found out, that the JTable never calls "getColumnClass" in the beginning but just when I want to click in the cell.

```
public class OrderTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private ArrayList<Orders> orders;
    private final String[] HEADER = {"Date", "isParty", "isHost"};

public OrderTableModel(ArrayList<Orders> orders)
{
    this.orders = orders;
}

public OrderTableModel(){
    orders = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return HEADER[column];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return orders.size() > 20 ? orders.size() : 20;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return HEADER.length;
}

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    System.out.println("in getColumnClass");
    switch(columnIndex)
    {
        case 1: return Boolean.class;
        case 2: return Boolean.class;
        default: return String.class;
    }

}


@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What renderer and editor are you using?

Comment: You're asking why your code is misbehaving, but you've posted code that we can neither compile, nor run, nor test. Please consider creating and posting a valid [mre]. I'm not requesting that you post your entire program, but rather a small program that runs and just demonstrates the problem and nothing more.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto: I would assume that the OP is using the default renderer and editor for Boolean.class since this *should* show a functioning JCheckBox, but you're correct, I don't see that there is enough information to answer this question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is coming!

Comment: And getRowCount() doesn't look safe. It should return `orders.size()` or else there is risk of throwing a NPE if the user tries to edit a non-existing order.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I created my own [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using your code, but fleshing it out so that it compiles, and runs, and the code works as expected: JCheckBoxes are seen where you would expect to see them. Please test this yourself to see:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class OrderTableFun  extends JPanel {
    private OrderTableModel model = new OrderTableModel();
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);

    public OrderTableFun() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            String name = "name " + i;
            boolean party = random.nextBoolean();
            boolean host = random.nextBoolean();
            Orders order = new Orders(name, party, host);
            model.addOrders(order);
        }

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        OrderTableFun mainPanel = new OrderTableFun();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("OrderTableFun");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class OrderTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private ArrayList<Orders> orders;
    private final String[] HEADER = { "Date", "isParty", "isHost" };

    public OrderTableModel(ArrayList<Orders> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    public OrderTableModel() {
        orders = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return HEADER[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // !! return orders.size() > 20 ? orders.size() : 20;
        return orders.size(); // !!
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return HEADER.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        System.out.println("in getColumnClass");
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 1:
            return Boolean.class;
        case 2:
            return Boolean.class;
        default:
            return String.class;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Orders order = (Orders) orders.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            String name = (String) aValue;
            order.setName(name);
            break;
        case 1:
            Boolean party = (Boolean) aValue;
            order.setParty(party);
        case 2:
            Boolean host = (Boolean) aValue;
            order.setHost(host);
        }
        fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }

    public void addOrders(Orders order) {
        orders.add(order);
        fireTableRowsInserted(getRowCount() - 1, getRowCount());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Orders order = (Orders) orders.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return order.getName();
        case 1:
            return order.isParty();
        case 2:
            return order.isHost();

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Orders {
    String name;
    boolean party;
    boolean host;

    public Orders(String name, boolean party, boolean host) {
        this.name = name;
        this.party = party;
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isParty() {
        return party;
    }

    public void setParty(boolean party) {
        this.party = party;
    }

    public boolean isHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(boolean host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

}
```

I've changed getRowCount to reflect the real number of Orders objects available.

Comment: Thank you! I just finished my own example and it works too... I really don't know what's wrong...

Comment: @asparagus: then you need to keep working to isolate the problem. Study the differences between  your actual code and your working code. Then modify one or the other until they both behave the same.

Comment: I got it... I am so sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I set a DefaultCellRenderer in the GUI to center things:

```
    DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.CENTER );

    for(int i = 0;i<table1.getColumnCount();i++)
        table1.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
```

which, I think, got "asked" by the JTable for what the Cells Class is instead of the in the model implemented getColumnClass method!

Comment: This is a bit frustrating for us since nowhere in the original question was there information that would allow us to be able to figure this out or provide an answer without making wild guesses. **This** is one of the main reasons that you should strive to provide a decent [mre] with any debugging type question, since you otherwise may very well not be posting the offending code.

Comment: This is one reason that my "answer" is a community wiki answer -- one that gives me no reputation credit in any way since it really isn't an answer as the question was unanswerable. But glad that you understand my point.